# How to subtract or find the differences from this output?

Tags: python, function, numpy, random, subtraction

Beginner here, just a week into Python.
So what I'm trying to do is figure out how to find the differences from the output I get.
Let's say I got [ 5  8 10  8 11]
Now I want to 8-5, 10-8, 8-10, 11-8.
How do I achieve that? enlighten me.

```
import numpy as np
import random
ll = list(range(5))

a = np.array(range(5))

b = np.array(random.choices(ll, k=5))

c = np.array([5])

print(a+b+c)
```

Comment: What things you have tried tho?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem related to your stated problem.  Also, since it's your first week I would suggest focusing on Python core functionality rather than libraries such as Numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way by using list comprehension:

```
>>> out = [7, 7, 10, 9, 12]  # a normal python list
>>> out_diff = [ (i-j) for j, i in zip(out[:-1], out[1:]) ]
>>> out_diff
[0, 3, -1, 3]
```

And since you're using numpy, its more easy:

```
>>> out[:-1] - out[1:]  # without using functions
array([ 0, -3,  1, -3])
```

Or use [np.diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html):

```
>>> np.diff(out)  # assumed 'out' is a numpy array instance
array([ 0,  3, -1,  3])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the function "**ediff1d**"  inside the **Numpy** module. For more information visit this link:[numpy.ediff1d documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html)

See example code:

```
import numpy as np

array = [5, 8, 10, 8, 11]
print(array)
print(np.ediff1d(array))
```

Output:

```
[5, 8, 10, 8, 11]
[ 3  2 -2  3]
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to implement it

```
lst=[5,8,10,8,11]
new_lst=[]
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
    new_lst.append(lst[i]-lst[i-1])
```